# How to pop up an error dialog in Scene when an error occurs in javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a code that when deleting a non-existent element in an array throws an error. And I want to draw some kind of error dialog box when throwing this error. I'm a bit confused on how to implement this in JavaFX

```
public static JMXMessage getMessage(QueueControl queueControl) {
 JMXHeaders jmxHeaders;
 JMXMessage jmxMessage;
 String body;
 String replyTo = null;
 String correlationId = null;
 try {
  CompositeData[] messages = queueControl.browse();
  j = queueLength - i;
  if (j > queueLength - 1) {
   i = 1;
   j = queueLength - i;
  }
  if (j < 0) {
  i = queueLength;
  j = 0;
 }

 TabularData stringProps = (TabularData) messages[j].get(CompositeDataConstants.STRING_PROPERTIES);
 for (CompositeData o : (Collection<CompositeData>) stringProps.values()) {
  Object key = o.get("key");
   if (key.equals("JMSReplyTo")) {
    replyTo = o.get("value").toString();
   }
  if (key.equals("JMSCorrelationID")) {
 correlationId = o.get("value").toString();
  }
 }
 jmxHeaders = new JMXHeaders(messages[j].get(CompositeDataConstants.TYPE).toString(),
 messages[j].get(CompositeDataConstants.EXPIRATION).toString(),
 messages[j].get(CompositeDataConstants.DURABLE).toString(),
 replyTo,
 messages[j].get(CompositeDataConstants.MESSAGE_ID).toString(),
 messages[j].get(CompositeDataConstants.TIMESTAMP).toString(),
 correlationId,
 messages[j].get(CompositeDataConstants.PRIORITY).toString());

 body = (String) messages[j].get(CompositeDataConstants.TEXT_BODY);
 jmxMessage = new JMXMessage(jmxHeaders, body);
 queueControl.removeMessage(Long.parseLong(messages[j].get(CompositeDataConstants.MESSAGE_ID).toString()));
 queueLength = queueControl.browse().length;
 return BuildGet.serializationAndDeserializationMessage(jmxMessage);
 } catch (Exception e) {
 throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
 }
```

I don't understand how to display an error window when an error occurs

Comment: Typically you would just catch an exception (or detect via programming logic that an error condition had occurred) and show a window or alert. It's not clear what the specific problem you're facing is.

Comment: How to show it in current Scene?

Comment: You can't show an "error window" in the current window (or scene); that's an oxymoron. To show some kind of message in the current scene, just manipulate the scene graph in the usual way (e.g. add something to its root, or another pane in the root, or change the text or visibility of a label, etc.). Again, the question is not specific enough.

Comment: [Dialogs are demoed at makery](https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/),

Answer (score -3):

If what you mean is to pop up an alert to the user, you can use `Alert`. Put it in the catch section.  Here is a good resource: https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/.

You can implement it like that:

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
alert.setTitle("Error");
alert.setHeaderText(null);
alert.setContentText("An error has occured!");
alert.showAndWait();
```

code modified, I didn't notice this code is running with JavaFX instead of JFrame.

Comment: `JOptionPane` in a `JavaFX` app is very bad practice.

Comment: If all the OP wanted was an alert, he/she should use something like https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/.

Comment: This answer is utterly wrong. You should not use a `JOptionPane` in a JavaFX application.

Comment: thanks, I didn's notice he's using JavaFx instead of JFrame. I edited the answer

Comment: When using an Alert for this, it is a good idea to set the Alert’s [expandableContent](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/DialogPane.html#setExpandableContent(javafx.scene.Node)) node to a non-editable TextArea containing the full stack trace of the exception.